# How to create redirects workers in cloudflare workers within wrangler.toml

Tags: serverless, cloudflare, netlify, cloudflare-workers

I'm in the process of moving from netlify functions to cloudfare workers but i'm kinda stuck on how to create redirects for multiple workers.

Coming from netlify, one could do this in the netlify.toml and it works.

```
  [[ redirects ]]
  from = "/hello"
  to = "/.netlify/builders/hellobuilder"
  status = 200
```

How can i achieve this with cloudflare workers?